# Rename a Sheet with the current date on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a code to copy all cells of a sheet and paste it in a new sheets in values with the original format. I want also to rename automatically the new sheet with the current date, I've tried this:

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Name = szToday
```

But the last line doesn't work to reach what I want.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sheet name cannot be blank. Since you have not defined `szToday`, it is blank.

Is this what you are trying

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
szToday = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
ActiveSheet.Name = szToday
```

Or simply

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
```

or a one liner

```
Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
```

Comment: So, szToday is an element that I have to define, thank you.